# Updating multiple tables data from different databases having same column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have `11 databases` in which I'm having tables contains `User Details` i.e. all employee details. There I have a column "`Status"(which is 1 for Active and 0 for Inactive)`. I have a regular tasks for updating "`Status`" column value `0 or 1` for mentioned employees and for that, I have to go through all the databases then User table then I have to update. The same task i have to do for all the database and it consumes a lot of time.
If I will get a short `Query` or `Procedure` that I have to run once and will do all updation at once then, it would be a great help.

Comment: can't you create a SQL script that has a "conn user/psw@db" for each database that you want to do you updates?

Comment: Why do you have 11 databases?

Comment: Hi Sagar... I have 11 different live Dot net Applications  for which I have to Full n Final for the Users under this.

Comment: need of 11 databases?

Comment: There are 11 different live Dot Net Applications for the Client. Every applications is having its own database.

Comment: Are you DBs all on the same RDBMS? If so, which one?

Comment: And these eleven databases are a mixture of SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL? I

Comment: SQL Server only

Comment: Aleksej... Yes all are on the same RDBMS...

Comment: Is there one master database which has read and write access on all the other databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of possible options.

You could build an SSIS package to connect to each database and do the necessary updates provided the criteria of which employees to update and what to update them to could be found within the database or some external source such as a text file.

Alternatively, you could use SQLCMD mode in SQL Server Management Studio and then within your SQL script use `CONNECT` command to switch to each server and database something like this...

```
:CONNECT Server1 
USE Database1

--put your update SQL script

:CONNECT Server2 
USE Database2

--put your update SQL script

...
```

These links provide some further information on using SQLCMD mode...

[Connecting to multiple servers in a Query Window using SQLCMD](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Changing%20the%20SQL%20Server%20connection%20within%20an%20SSMS%20Query%20Windows%20using%20SQLCMD%20Mode.aspx)

[SQL Server SQLCMD Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-sqlcmd-basics/)

Noel

Comment: Is there any other shorter way for doing this?

Comment: I cannot think of a shorter way. Both of my suggestions require some initial effort, but after that you just run them. Seems like that would be better than connecting to 11 servers and databases individually.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you have 11 databases.

**Problem** : First, you are using very bad approach for database design,

**What really Happens** : When you are using multiple databases and you need to check in every database, then the server needs to connect to different database again and again, which takes very more time compared to switching into the tables, because of connection handling.

**Solution** : In your case, you have only one option to connect different databases in loops and then run the query in the loop for every DB.

**Suggestion** : you should keep all the data in the same database, you can use an extra column in tables to keep track your data to different entities.

Comment: 11 database.. why so because, Client is using 11 different applications so that databases also will be there for each and every application